# Is this a mathematical statement - "$x^2 + 1 = 0$ has 12 real roots"?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Is this a mathematical statement?
 $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has $12$ real roots
can anyone tell me is it a mathematical statement or not

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Yes, it is – albeit it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes $$x^2+1 = 0 \text{ has 12 real roots}$$ is a mathematical statement.

A mathematical statement is a statement that we can assign a truth value to it. That means as long as  the statement is either true or false it is a mathematical statement. It does not matter if we know the actual truth value of the statement. In your case the statement is false.

Answer (score 3):

A mathematical statement should (according to me at least although it is rather vague) be a correctly formulated statement which involves mathematics.

$$x^2+1 = 0 \text{ has 12 real roots}$$
is clearly about mathematics and correctly formulated. Thus it is a mathematical statement, even though it is false. There is nothing demanding that a mathematical statement needs to be true in order to be a mathematical statement, but it needs to be well formulated you cant just say 
$$alsdkjhflkajdhgflkjh+++sdfadhjkgafs +1+1= asduh+0$$
Since this is not well defined what it even means, even though it involve mathematical parts such as $1+1 = $, it is not a mathematical statement, but rather only jubberish.

Answer (score 0):

It's a *mathematical* statement, I suppose, but it's certainly not a *true* statement!